# Build OpenCV 4.x with Anaconda bindings (Linux)

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, anaconda

I've been trying to stay with Anaconda for all projects (neural net development, etc), so I have the Anaconda folder in the front of the path.  Problems arise when trying to build OpenCV 4.1.2 (master).  First few error messages listed at bottom.

I'd also like to make sure that OpenCV's Python bindings are built for Anaconda.  This also seems to be problematic, though I haven't had much chance to pursue it yet.

Is there an elegant workaround, or do I need to abandon attempts to use Anaconda for OpenCV?

Error messages indicate that OpenCV/Cmake has trouble with folders that are 'shadowed' by Anaconda:

---

CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1471 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target opencv_test_videoio
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

```
runtime library [libgstbase-1.0.so.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/Anaconda/3.7/lib
runtime library [libgstreamer-1.0.so.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/Anaconda/3.7/lib
runtime library [libgobject-2.0.so.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/Anaconda/3.7/lib
```

etc....

Comment: try to work on virtue, or install by Anaconda navigator

Answer (score 0):

Development with conda packages (and especially with compiled libraries with many dependencies like opencv) is pretty hard.  To be specific, I mean changing code in opencv and rebuilding it - hacking on opencv.

If you only need to create packages of some specific version of opencv, to then use in conda environments, you can use conda-build to build packages.  There is a good recipe for opencv at https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock